# Could we get a different font for <kbd> text?

Tags: feature-request, design, kbd

We're able to use `<kbd>` tags to indicate keyboard input, but I noticed an issue with the font used:

<kbd>I</kbd> vs. <kbd>l</kbd>

Is that a lower-case L or an upper-case i?  You have to view the post's source to find out.

Could we have a font used for `<kbd>` tags that makes the difference explicit?  It tends to be important that manual computer input be accurate.

Comment: I vote for Comic Sans!

Comment: Agreed; at the least it should be Courier.

Comment: No! It must be Papyrus!